# Finding the smallest/highest value within date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4GZl.png)hello I'm a beginner and don't know where to start. My problem is how to find the smallest value of a specific cell and the date adjacent to it considering multiple smallest value can pick any of the smallest value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCEgQ.png)

I'm using this value to find the date of the smallest value

```
=INDEX(B4:B41684,MATCH(MINIFS(D4:D41684,A4:A41684,F6,B4:B41684,">="&H2,B4:B41684,"<="&H3),D4:D41684,0))
```

while

```
(MINIFS(D4:D41684,A4:A41684,F6,B4:B41684,">="&H2,B4:B41684,"<="&H3)
```

to find the smallest.

At first with small arrays/sample the values I'm getting is right but when I used huge sample the results are wrong

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: If you're a beginner this is way beyond your pay grade. I'm not but it is beyond mine. However, I can tell you where to start. Start with researching formulas that combine the SMAll/LARGE functions with multiple criteria (3 in your case) matches. You may not find the solution but you will understand enough of the problem to encourage you to give up. At least, that's what happened to me. If you absolutely need this, consider a User Defined VBA Function (UDF) but be sure to try your hand at writing it yourself before you ask for it on a platter.

Comment: Please add your desired result at least.

Comment: to find the date adjacent to the smallest value I'm using =INDEX(B4:B41684,MATCH(MINIFS(D4:D41684,A4:A41684,F6,B4:B41684,">="&H2,B4:B41684,"<="&H3),D4:D41684,0)) but for larger arrays i get wrong values. For smaller arrays it is right

Comment: Please provide a **small** sample of data that we can use to reproduce your problem. **Edit** your question to provide it as **TEXT** that can be copy/pasted into a worksheet. You can read Help for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for hints how to do this.

Comment: for a small sample data that formula I'm using is good but for a large sample data which ranges a year the resulting value is wrong but I'll upload a second picture for sampling you can randomize the number and fill up the date till November maybe to get a large sample.

Answer (score 0):

I would use MINIFS() but that may depend on your version, see:

[image]

Comment: I already used =INDEX(B4:B41684,MATCH(MINIFS(D4:D41684,A4:A41684,F6,B4:B41684,">="&H2,B4:B41684,"<="&H3),D4:D41684,0)) but for a larger table. I get wrong values

Comment: Well, I could not guess what you had already used. @RedoneilRagojoReyes